# Firefox add-on - `this` works in one method but fails in another method of the same object

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, this

I am developing an add-on for Firefox (3.6.*). in the following code `notify` called from inside `init` works fine, but I get an error saying `this.notify is not a function` when it is called from within `onPageLoad`. Why is that?

Also when I change the call to `myextobj.notify('title', 'msg')`, it works. The same is true for accessing variables. So, what is the difference between `this` and the object name as a prefix?

```
var myextobj = {
  init: function() {
    this.notify('init', 'We are inside init');
    ...
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser  
    if(appcontent)  
      appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, true);
  },
  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    this.notify('onPageLoad', 'We are inside onPageLoad');
    ...
  },

  notify: function (title, text) {  
    Components.classes['@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1'].  
      getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService).  
      showAlertNotification(null, title, text, false, '', null);  
  }  
};
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myextobj.init(); }, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, true);
```

you just add the function that is hold in `onPageLoad` as event handler. The connection to the object is lost and `this` will refer to the global object when executed.

Just create an anonymous function as you do for the `load` event:

```
var that = this; // capture reference to object
appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    that.onPageLoad(event);
    // myextobj.onPageLoad(event); should also work in this case
}, true);
```

---

Remember that functions are first class objects in JavaScript, they can be passed around like any other value. Functions have no reference to an object they are defined on, because they don't belong to that object. They are just another kind of data.

To which object `this` refers to in a function is decided upon execution and depends on the *context* the function is executed in. If you call `obj.func()` then the context is `obj`, but if you assign the function to another variable before like `var a = obj.func` (that is wat you do with adding the event handler (in a way)) and then call `a()`, `this` will refer to the global object (which is `window` most of the time).

Answer (score 2):

When `onPageLoad` is called for the event, 'this' would not be referring to your `myextobj`. Because it wasn't called in the context of your object `myextobj`.

The way I deal with this is, by having all member functions of an object using the following convention.

```
var myObj = {
   .....
   counter: 0,
   .....
   myFunction: function () {
     var t = myObj;
     t.myOtherFunc();
   },

   ....
   myOtherFunc: function() {
     var t = myObj;
     t.counter++;
   }
};
```

See how, I'm aliasing `myObj` as `t`, to save on typing and making my intent of using `this` clear.

Now you can call your methods safely from any context without worrying about what `this` would be referring to. Unless you really want the standard behavior; in that case, you may like to look at the `call` and `apply` methods. This link might help: [Function.apply and Function.call in JavaScript](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx)

- You may also want to look at a recent addition to JavaScript (would be available in FireFox 4): the `bind` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- Another link, which directly addresses your problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Answer (score 0):

The other way to add an event listener without losing track of `this` is to pass `this` itself as the event listener. However you are limited in that the function is always called `handleEvent`, so it's less useful if you have many listeners (unless they are all for different events, in which case you can switch on the event's type).